# WWW Publishing Service gives 503 error after Win10 FCU

Tags: windows, iis

The WWW Pub Service was working fine before I installed the Win10 Fall Creators Update.
Now I get this error
*HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.*

I'm simply trying to load a local web page with a browser (simple html, not asp.net page).
http://localhost/html/home/index.html

Edge and Firefox give the same error.

Is there anything in the Win10 FCU that would have made config changes in IIS?

PS. I also installed the latest version of Visual Studio Community ed 2017. But I don't think that should have affected IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop “Windows Process Activation Service” and “W3SVC” service and clean out (delete) all the files under C:\Inetpub\temp\AppPools*. Start your services and the sites should be back to work.

Source: https://www.ajeetyelandur.com/2017/10/Windows-10-Fall-Creators-update-crashes-App-Pool/